# how to display validations at angular2

Tags: validation, angular, typescript

I followed same sample with the code and tried to show validation when user removes the text in the input and show display messages.Unfortunately, when I remove the text field it does not show anything. Could you please check the code and tell me why I can not show the validation message ?

Regards
Alper

```
 <label for="name">SA / Rentennummer 005 :</label>
 <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" required 
  [(ngModel)]="Input.name" name="name"  #name="ngModel">
 <div [hidden]="name.valid || name.pristine"
     class="alert alert-danger">
    name is required
  </div>
```

In The typescript :

```
  Input= { name:'Alper'};
```

Comment: can you create a sample plunker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   form : FormGroup;
   this.form = fb.group({
      name : new FormControl({value: null}, Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(100)]))
    });


    <form class="form-details" role="form" name="registrationForm" [formGroup]="userForm">
            <div>
                <div class="row input-label">
                  <label class="form-label" for="name">First name</label>
                  <input
                    [formControl]="form.controls['name']"
                    type="text"
                    class="form-control"
                    id="form"
                    name="form">
                </div>
                <div *ngIf="!form.controls['name'].valid">field is required</div>
            </div>
          </form>
```